# Expand listview with animation (on few items - not the whole list)

Tags: android, list, listview, expand

I have a List with 6 items (strings) and the last item has the string "more options".

After clicking on "more options", the list should add 3 items between item5 and "more options" (last item). For example:

```
 - item1
 - item2
 - item3
 - item4
 - item5
 - "more options"
```

I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the Adapter that new items have been added to the list.

What's the best way to **animate** the expansion of the list from 6 items to 9 items without recreating the whole list?

Final look of the list (after adding item6, item7, and item8 with an animation):

```
 - item1
 - item2
 - item3
 - item4
 - item5
 - item6 (new)
 - item7 (new)
 - item8 (new)
 - "more options"
```

Is it bad practice/hacky to put outset every item needed and make item6, item7, item8 invisible? Whats the best way?

Comment: May this help https://github.com/karnshah8890/tech_andy/tree/master/ListviewAnimationDemo

Answer (score 1):

you have to create animation something like this

```
 private void enlarge(final View v, AnimationListener al)
{
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation anim = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
        {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1)
            {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight + (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds()
        {
            return true;
        }
    };

    if (al != null)
    {
        anim.setAnimationListener(al);
    }
    anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

then use this when adding items to the listview before that create AnimationListener

```
  AnimationListener al = new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0)
        {
            mAnimList.remove(index);

            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            vh.needInflate = true;

            mMyAnimListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
        }
    };
```

and finaly call

```
  enlarge(v, al);
```

Comment: Do you enlarge here every item for itself?

Comment: Yes this code will do for each item , if you want to extend only once you have to find length required for items to be added and then call this with last item before "more options".